# ReporteRS not obeying template bullets

Tags: r, reporters

I was trying to create a presentation using the `R` package `ReporteRS`. The unordered lists seems to obey only the limited options set by `ReporteRS`. Is there anyway to make get `ReporteRS` to obey the defaults within a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this, while not very elegant is to reset the slides using either `VBA` or `VBScript`. Below is my solution to reseting all the slides using `VBScript`. Simple drag and drop a file onto the script saved with a `.vbs` extension.

```
Dim inputFile
Dim objPresentation

inputFile = WScript.Arguments(0)
Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True
objPPT.Presentations.Open inputFile
Set objPresentation = objPPT.ActivePresentation

slideCount = objPresentation.Slides.Count

For i = 1 to slideCount
    objPresentation.Slides(i).Select
    objPresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("SlideReset")
Next

objPresentation.Save
objPPT.Quit
```